# Split iterator by separator

Tags: rust

Is there an ideomatic combinator-friendly way to split an iterator into multiple iterators?

There is a `split` function in slices, so I can achieve result I want by `collect`ing iterator into a `Vec<_>`, but i'm guessing it will make it iterate over all elements to collect result, making it not lazy.

So, is there a way to do the same thing without `collect`ing and without doing it manualy in `for` loops?

For example, in [AoC 2022 day 1](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/1) I need to split lines (iter of strings) by an empty line.

```rust
pub fn part_one(input: &str) -> Result<String> {
    let result = input.lines()
        //I don't want this `collect` here.
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .split(|line| line.is_empty())
        .map(|inventory| inventory.into_iter()
            .filter_map(|item| item.parse::<i32>().ok())
            .sum::<i32>()
        )
        .max().ok_or("I guess input was empty")?;

    Ok(result.to_string())
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is impossible to implement without collecting the values first.

Iterators are lazy, which means that to reach the separator we need to iterate over all items until it. So to get the second iterator we need to do that. But when we do that, we already iterated over all items of the first iterator, so we exhausted it.

This is technically possible by cloning the underlying iterator, if it impls `Clone` ([which `Lines` does](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/struct.Lines.html#impl-Clone-for-Lines%3C%27a%3E)), but I think doing so will be more expensive than collecting the items. Anyway, I don't know such function.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can just reverse the splits, that is first split by an empty line, to get each elves values and then split those values:

```rust
pub fn part_one(input: &str) -> Result<String, &'static str> {
    let result = input
        .split("\n\n")
        .map(|elf| {
            elf.lines()
                .filter_map(|item| item.parse::<i32>().ok())
                .sum::<i32>()
        })
        .max()
        .ok_or("I guess input was empty")?;

    Ok(result.to_string())
}
```

In the general case it's not possible to solve that problem without collecting or cloning though, read [Chayim Friedman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76869067/442760) for an explanation why.